# How to replace a certain number of row values/text in a certain column with different text/values in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a file with a column (5 in the pic) that is filled with X's.  I need to replace those X's with different letters.  However, I need a certain amount of rows in that column to be the same letter, and then for another set of rows to be another letter, and so on.  Example shown in 2nd pic.  To be more clear, I need lines 2-10 to have the letter A in column 5, lines 11-20 to letter B, lines 21-30 the letter C, and so on.  Is there a way to do this in Linux replacing those X's in the file by giving the row/line ranges and the letter I want, but NOT saving to a new file? I need a faster way than by hand because I have over a million lines in the file, and I have about 5,000 files to change.

What I have

[image: What I have]

What I need

[image: What I need]

Comment: If you have GNU `awk` it has an "inplace" extension that allows you to replace the original file with the result.

Comment: Please paste tables as plain text instead of images. You can format them as code to preserve plain text formatting. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/967621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '{ match($0,$5);printf "%s%c%s\n",substr($0,1,RSTART-1),64+$6,substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH) }' file
```

Using awk, use the match function to find the starting position of the 5th space delimited field. We then print the start of the line to the 5th field, the character code of 64 + the 6th delimited field and then the rest of the field.

sample used:

```
ATOM    1 CA HIE X 1    105.967 123.567 112.345 0.00    0.00
ATOM    1 CA HIE X 2    105.967 123.567 112.345 0.00    0.00
ATOM    1 CA HIE X 3    105.967 123.567 112.345 0.00    0.00
```

Output:

```
ATOM    1 CA HIE A 1    105.967 123.567 112.345 0.00    0.00
ATOM    1 CA HIE B 2    105.967 123.567 112.345 0.00    0.00
ATOM    1 CA HIE C 3    105.967 123.567 112.345 0.00    0.00
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It looks like this will work.  However, I understood about half of what you explained.  What part of this code would allow me to change how many lines get the letter A, and B, and so on?